# react-native-splash-screen library android error

Tags: android, xml, react-native-splash-screen

I have implemented `react-native-splash-screen` library to have splash screens for both the platforms android and iOS. For iOS, Everything is working fine, but for android I am getting an error when showing modal component to my react native application. I have checked through the configuration I have been added for the splash screen there's nothing missing with the assets/resources. Please help me fixing it, if somebody knows about it.

**The error says:**

[image]